# How can i use GMailApp to access to user's domain account

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to know how to use the object [GmailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app) from Google Apps Script to access to different user inboxes of the same domain. Is it possible? How?

Thanks in advance,
Ernesto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately that is not possible. Apps Script only allows access the active user's data. To access their inbox you'll need them to run the script.