# GmailApp getAliases() for user viewing web-app

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am writing an app script using GmailApp, and I want the

```
getAliases();


function getAliases() {
  var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases();
  Logger.log(aliases);
  for (x = 0; x < aliases.length; x++) {
    Logger.log("Aliase " + x + ": " + aliases); 
  }
  return aliases;
}
```

method to return a list of the User's aliases, but after deploying it always returns my own list of aliases, not the current user who is looking at the web-app. It looks like until they deploy the app, they don't get their own aliases.

Is there a different method to use, or am I calling it wrong?

Judging by the answer to: [How can i use GMailApp to access to user's domain account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23757294/how-can-i-use-gmailapp-to-access-to-users-domain-account) it looks like it might not be possible, but I would like to double check!

Answer (score 0):

From the Google Apps Script [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getAliases()) itself, `getAliases()` gets the list of the emails that are **set up as aliases for this account in Gmail**.

Here is the example code.

```
// Log the aliases for this Gmail account and send an email as the first one.
var me = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases();
Logger.log(aliases);
if (aliases.length > 0) {
GmailApp.sendEmail(me, 'From an alias', 'A message from an alias!', {'from': aliases[0]});
} else {
GmailApp.sendEmail(me, 'No aliases found', 'You have no aliases.');
}
```

then it returns a `String[]` as an array of **aliases for this account**. So it is clearly stated here that you will get the aliases for the account itself not the current user who is looking at the web-app.

Comment: I didn't know that this account meant the account itself. Do you by any chance know if there is a way to bypass this or get this another way?

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but that meaning from the documentation is the only one that I know. And as of now, I don't have time to try that.